# Есть ли метод, что бы убрать одну последнюю цифру(int) или последний символ(string)

Tags: java, строки, методы

```
  String stringFirstForRandom = Integer.toString(lastForRandom);

  int firstForRandom = stringFirstForRandom.lastIndexOf("0");
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(stringFirstForRandom);
  sb.deleteCharAt(firstForRandom);
  stringFirstForRandom = sb.toString(); 
  firstForRandom = Integer.parseInt(stringFirstForRandom);
  return (int)(firstForRandom + Math.random() * lastForRandom);
```

Это мое решение, но получилось коряво. Есть ли способ сделать все поаккуратнее?
Надо убрать либо последнюю цифру в int переменной либо последний символ в string.

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение. так как у вас явно какая-то более сложная задача, чем просто убрать 1 символ.

Comment: Для целого числа достаточно поделить на 10

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не могу понять, как я не догадался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходное значение - это целое число:

```
int someNumber = 1234;

(int) someNumber / 10
// или
Integer.valueOf(someNumber / 10)
```

Если строка:

```
String someNumber = "1234";
someNumber.substring(0, someNumber.length() - 1)
```